# std::unique_ptr operator[] vs. raw ptr dynamic array operator[]

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, indexing, unique-ptr

I have the following code sample:

```
void foo(int size)
{
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> data = std::make_unique<uint8_t>(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
    {
        data[i] = 1;
        data[i + 1] = 2;
    }
}
```

The actual code does actual calculations, but that does not matter for this question and was removed for simplicity's sake.

When compiling and running this code with optimizations turned on, everything works great and runs fast.
However, when running without any optimizations, this code is much slower than:

```
void foo(int size)
{
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> data = std::make_unique<uint8_t>(size);
    uint8_t* dataPtr = data.get();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
    {
        dataPtr[i] = 1;
        dataPtr[i + 1] = 2;
    }
}
```

To investigate this a bit more, I ran multiple variations of the indexing operator with this dynamic array through compiler explorer (godbolt.org).
Compiling with clang and -O3 optimizations, all variations result in the same assembly.
However, compiling without any optimizations, the unique_ptr only sample has a call to the unique_ptr operator[], which seems to be causing the slowdown.

Why is the operator[] of the unique_ptr much slower without optimizations? From the documentation I see that the operator[] should be equivalent to unique_ptr.get()[].
Is it doing some safety checks without optimizations? If so, which ones?

Comment: How big is the slowdown you are seeing?  "much" is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without optimisations, there is the overhead of calling `operator[]` and passing the index as an argument. With optimisations, the compiler can inline the entire function to avoid the overhead of calling the function (and since it results in identical assembly, you already know that the performance will be the same).

This is one of the many reasons that profiling/benchmarking without optimisations leads to incorrect results: zero-cost abstractions will have a cost that they wouldn't normally have in your production build.

Comment: Did you check if `operator[]` has debugging checks?  That is plausible, and not addressed here.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont [libstdc++ checks that `get() != nullptr`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/unique_ptr.h;h=805ad76c233d63650d67fad3c66b107d4130c956;hb=refs/heads/master#l659) if `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` is defined before any headers are included (which is not the case here), [libc++ has no check](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/9f76788b0930ed48f5f20a25f1b30d63c8486531/libcxx/include/memory#L1846), [Microsoft's STL also has no check](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/ac4fde764ae716512bdd67e0e9577bd53947bc3d/stl/inc/memory#L3397).

Comment: Either way, if the optimisation changed the behaviour, you should time with the optimisations that would be used in production

Comment: sometimes debug performance matters; if something is too much slower in debug, the program can become unusable, and you need to use the program to debug it.  The OP asked about why it was slower; add your findings to improve the answer!